# Neo4j getting child nodes of multiple parents

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've just recently started using neo4j and I've run into an issue. There doesn't seem to be an answer to this on here but I might also be wording it incorrectly. I'm building a small site that categorizes music. There are multiple song nodes with `BELONGS_TO` relationships to genre nodes. How can I get every song that belongs to a set of user specified genres.

For example. Song1, Song2, Song3 all belong to both Pop and Electronic. Song4 just belongs to Pop. How can I query to get every song belonging to both Pop and Electronic? In this case Song1, Song2, an Song3.

I've been struggling with this for a while. This is what I have so far but it doesn't return anything. If I replace `AND` with `OR` I get all the songs that belong to one of those genres.

```
MATCH (n:Song)-[r:BELONGS_TO]->(Genre)
WHERE (n)-[r]->(Genre{name:"Pop"}) AND (n)-[r]->(Genre{name:"Electronic"})
RETURN n
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do in the `WHERE` clause you should actually do in the `MATCH` clause.  Here you go:

```
MATCH (g1:Genre {name: "Pop"})<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(popElectronicSongs:Song)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(g2:Genre {name: "Electronic"});
RETURN popElectronicSongs;
```

You can actually do quite a lot with just the `MATCH` clause as you can see here.  The `WHERE` bit usually gets used for filtering based on various predicates.  For example you might say `WHERE popElectronicSongs.title =~ /S.*/` to filter for only songs whose name starts with S.

Comment: I believe the only reason that `MATCH` syntax is supported in the `WHERE` clause is because sometimes you need to do something like `WHERE NOT((a)-[r]-(b))`

Comment: Also, much less important notes:  You don't need the `g1` and `g2` variables as you're not returning them.  Also, I would call the song vairable `popElectronicSong`.  The `MATCH` clause is best thought of as matching one subgraph at a time and hence here it would be matching one pop/electronic song at a time